# Black lines around alpha cutoff in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency

I have a node setup that applies a png texture to a character's face for the eyelids, but there is a black line around the alpha cutoff. I obviously don't want them there. Take a look at the images. (On the eyelid mask, I made the background white so you can see it better. Original image is transparent.)
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe, if it's not a problem for you, share your file with the images packed inside: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Actually I already found a solution to the problem! I simply added a greater than node on the image alpha>mix factor connection.

Answer (score 2):

I found the soultion, it was to add a greater-then node to the image-alpha>mix-factor connection.

Comment: Hi :). Don't forget to 'accept' your answer. Question keeps popping up as unanswered ;)